# Woocommerce Postcode/zip two seperate fields (numbers & letters)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zipcode, postal-code

A client of mine wants to keep the numbers and the letters of the postcode seperate ex. 4800 AA.
Is there a way to do this easily? I've been looking around for some plugins with which i could do something like this, but i haven't found anything yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fields in the front-end, back end or a DB level?

Comment: Take a look at 'Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters' of the WooCommerce Codex documentation http://customizing%20checkout%20fields%20using%20actions%20and%20filters/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but your link doesn't work. Also, i've found this post, but i'm getting a blank page (500 error code): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/how-to-reorder-billing-fields-in-woocommerce-checkout-template

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/